# Trying to convert character to datetime using as_datetime() but getting a wrong format in R

Tags: r, datetime, char, tidyverse, lubridate

I am facing an issue to correctly convert started_at and ended_at field to `datatime` format. when im using `as_datetime()` the years are getting changed from 2021 to 2001. Help.

initial data as char : 01-07-2020 00:00

after using

```r
total_trips$started_at <- as_datetime(total_trips$started_at)
```

I'm getting 2001-07-20 20:00:00

tried using

```r
total_trips$started_at <- as_datetime(total_trips$started_at, "%m%d%Y %H%m")
```

I was getting the following error:

```
Error in C_force_tz(time, tz = tzone, roll) : CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "%d%m%Y %H:%M"
```

what's going wrong??

Comment: When i tried this

```
total_trips$started_at = as_datetime(total_trips$started_at,format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```
my whole column turned to NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the format to match your data, your data is separated by dash (-), so the correct format would be `%d-%m-%Y %R` or `%d-%m-%Y %H:%M`. Notice that `%R` is equivalent to `%H:%M`.

```r
library(lubridate)

as_datetime("01-07-2020 00:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y %R")
#> [1] "2020-07-01 UTC"
as_datetime("01-07-2020 17:59", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
#> [1] "2020-07-01 17:59:00 UTC"
```

Learn more about date-time conversion format [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html)

Comment: Thanks alot! it worked. I had no idea that '-' was ruining my code. will keep it in mind next time!